# How do I create a decision tree like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a decision tree (if that's the correct name) like the one below (https://www.onefamily.com/lifetime-isa/, under the 'Am I eligible for a Lifetime ISA?')

[image: Decision Tree]

Comment: Hi Jason, welcome to stackoverflow. If you provide pictures/examples in the question, more people are likely to answer than if they have to follow links.

Comment: Added image thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/njmcode/pen/Fjcai - simple example pen, I would delete all the JS after the "test code" comment. As far as making it look like what you have in example you'll need some CSS. But essentially you would hide/show sections based on what the user clicks.... As you show sections you can also autoscroll down to the new ones that show up like they do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with wanted questions, answers and comments.

```js
function ask(question) {
    if (!question) return;
    var answer = prompt(question.question + '\n' + question.answers.map(({ answer }, i) => '\n' + i + ' ' + answer));
    if (answer in question.answers) {
        if (question.answers[answer].comment) {
            alert(question.answers[answer].comment);
            return;
        }
        ask(question.answers[answer]);
    }
}

var tree = {
        question: 'First of all, are you aged between 18 and 39 and a UK resident?',
        answers: [
            {
                answer: 'Yes',
                question: 'Great! Next, how are you planning to use your Lifetime ISA?',
                answers: [
                    {
                        answer: 'I\'m buying my first (house)',
                        question: 'Is your first home going to cost less than £450,000?',
                        answers: [
                            {
                                answer: 'Yes',
                                question: 'And lastly, are you planning on buying your first home within the next five years?',
                                answers: [
                                    {
                                        answer: 'Yes',
                                        comment: 'It looks like you could be eligible for a Lifetime ISA.'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        answer: 'No',
                                        comment: 'It looks like you could be eligible for a Lifetime ISA.'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                answer: 'No',
                                comment: 'Based on the current government rules, Lifetime ISAs can be used to purchase homes costing £450,000 or less.'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        answer: 'I\'m saving for my (...)',
                        question: 'What is your employment status?',
                        answers: [
                            {
                                answer: 'Employed',
                                comment: 'It looks like you could be eligible for a Lifetime ISA.'
                            },
                            {
                                answer: 'Self Employed',
                                comment: 'It looks like you could be eligible for a Lifetime ISA.'
                            },
                            {
                                answer: 'Not Employed',
                                comment: 'It looks like you could be eligible for a Lifetime ISA.'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                answer: 'No',
                comment: 'Our Lifetime ISAs are only available to UK residents aged between 18 and 39.'
            }
        ]
    },
    question = tree;

ask(question);
```